# Is it possible to have Experience Manager footprint values come from a Tridion Category

Tags: experience-manager, ambient-data-framework

The [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=UIU4SDLT2011SP1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=UIU4SDLT2011SP1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=Footprint&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1362512388844&currentQuery=Footprint&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_50676444753A41A9BE9CA0178D27E7A5&query=Footprint&scope=&filename=CreatingACustomFPForThePreviewTab.xml&docid=task_50676444753A41A9BE9CA0178D27E7A5&inner_id=&tid=2f166b78-bb79-4d78-8391-0350da2c8c11&addHistory=true&resource=) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) clearly states how to set up custom footprint lists to enable you to preview your content under different conditions. Here you typically define a list of values in a config file which an Editor can select for to define different scenarios. Is it possible to have this list from a Tridion category, rather than in the config file? I would want to display the keyword title to the Editor, and pass the keyword URI to the staging website as an Ambient Data Framework claim value.

I am guessing this is not possible, but want to double check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it should be possible.

You can create your own 'data type' and its 'editor'

As an exercise we created an google map editor that allow you to click on a map and put the lat/long on the adf, with a cartridge translation that to a country,

this could just as easy be a dropdown that get's its value by a webservice call or something

I'll do some investigation and update the answer

Comment: Thanks - Good to know its possible, I guess I was kind of hoping it would be easier than creating real code and calling webservice and stuff :o( No need to go any further now, so dont kill yourself finding an example - just exploring the boundaries of the product...

Comment: Basically, you can do anything as a custom footprint -- but we only provide editors for types like text, dates, and simple lists. As Gertjan mentioned, you can create your own editor for any other types of footprint you want to expose. So it's very flexible, but you do need to do the work yourself :)